Права доступа в Linux для пользователя,не входящего в sudoers
Есть сервер, на который у меня есть доступ (логин и пароль).Зайдя под этим пользователем на этот сервер обнаружено, что мой пользователь не входит в sudoers. Дополнительная информация отсутствует, у меня есть только один этот пользователь.
Нужно прочесть файл /tmp/somefolder/file на  этом сервере.
Директория /tmp/somefolder имеет права drwxr-xr-x, а файл /tmp/somefolder/file имеет права -rw-r-----.
Я нахожусь где-то в системе, неизвестно в какой директории.
Я не владею директорией /tmp/somefolder и не вхожу в группу, владеющую этой директорией, аналогично я не владею файлом /tmp/somefolder/file и не вхожу в группу, владеющую им.
Каким образом я могу посмотреть содержимое файла  /tmp/somefolder/file?

При таких вводных — никаким

Легально - никак. На то и система прав, чтобы ограничивать доступ. А так погуглите на тему linux privilege escalation

@Pak Uula,благодарю!

@andreymal,благодарю!
